# content expand on overflow

Tags: html, css

I'm somewhat of a designer but i kind of suck at css, and cannot seem to get the site to expand right when the content changes. I hope you guys can help...

css:
http://pastebin.com/CasrrGe9

html:
http://pastebin.com/WN8XhAHd

I revised the html with the absolute path to the images

Comment: It's hard to see what you're talking about without absolute URLs to the images.

Comment: Yeah, if you'd rephrase this so it's easier to see what happens I bet you'd get more answers

Comment: could you explain what kind of page are you trying to generate. Is it some sort of gallery? And ur html doesn't seems to be revised to absolute paths to me.

Comment: @everyone i seriously revised the code this time, pastebin doesn't update the post it just creates a new url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can slice anything from Photoshop or other tools, but don't do like this. Slice important part only.

I recode back your site. I used only two images. Look at http://jsbin.com/esijo5/edit

[Happy new year](http://www.google.com/search?q=learn+css+xhtml) ;)

Answer (score 4):

You seriously need to refactor all your CSS.

It seems to me that you're using Photoshop or a design tool like this to design/cut and automatically generate html/css.

If those did a correct code, a lot of people would lose their job...

That said, I may be wrong, you did this yourself. And then, you need to learn not to code like a design tool ;)

In your case, you're designing in `absolute` position and fixed `width` and `height`.

It means that every element on your page is positioned once and for all, that if the content in your element is wider than its container, it will expand but won't influence any other absolute positioned element.

Now, you can't ask someone to refactor all your CSS here. **[You should start to learn it](http://www.cssbasics.com/)** and then ask specific question here if needed.

[You can train here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/BzmzE/).

Comment: @Chouchenous, you are rather right, I have never seen this sort of css written manually.

Answer (score 1):

I would just recommend little things like changing all those id's of index-## to have the positioned declared once

```
#index-01,#index-02,#index-03,#index-04{
position:absolute;
}
```

Clean it all up then start worrying about other things, as otherwise you are going to be in a real mess in about an hour or so.

**you shouldn't be positioning them at all though**

You should declare one class that is in control of all the divs and that is floating left:

```
.float_left {float:left;}
.clear_both {clear:both}
```

And apply that to each of the divs you want to use then at the end clear the float

```
<div class="float_left"><img src="index-1.jpg" /></div>
<div class="float_left"><img src="index-2.jpg" /></div>
<div class="float_left"><img src="index-3.jpg" /></div>
<div class="clear_both"></div>
```

Then the divs should expand automatically :)